# Customizing "Something went wrong" page by showing same header and footer as custom master page

Tags: 2013, error, master-page, publishing-site

Is there a way to customize that error page which says "Something went wrong" and then below it, it shows Correlation ID?

I want this page to use the same Master Page as my Publishing site is using and display some other message for e.g. "Please contact server admin" etc.

Comment: hi, did you get any solution to change the message

Comment: @MJaiswal Solution is given below by Marius although I never tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pages (because there are others) are not linked to being used on a Publishing site or Collaboration, but rather these are application pages changeable at the Web Application level - read more http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/07/09/how-to-change-system-application-pages.aspx (and example to replace the Error.aspx page find at http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/17/replace-default-pagenotfounderror-aspx-with-custom-error-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

On a Publishing site, specific to SharePoint 2013 there is a new Content Type linking to an Error Page - which you could replace ( https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Custom-Error-Pages.aspx)

Comment: I know this post is extremly old, but it shows why copying content to stackexchange is a good idea. Non of the links is still working for me.